# Show $a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3 \le 27$

Tags: inequality

Given $a, b, c, d$ are real numbers and $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2 = 9$ show that
$$a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3\le27$$

I have tried to do the following:

$$(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)^{\frac{3}{2}} = 27 \\ \text{after simplifying} \\ (a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3) + \frac{3}{2}(a^2b^2+(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)+c^2d^2)=27$$

By setting the following:

$$(a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3) + \frac{3}{2}(a^2b^2+(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)+c^2d^2)=(a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3) \\ \frac{3}{2}(a^2b^2+(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)+c^2d^2)=0 \\
(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)=-(a^2b^2+c^2d^2) \\ (a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3)+\frac{3}{2}(a^2b^2+-(a^2b^2+c^2d^2)+c^2d^2)=27 \\ (a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3)=27$$

and so we have shown the inequality to hold - does this proof work?

Comment: Are you asking for *some* proof or do you want to know if *your* proof works?

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2150951/42969

Comment: "after simplifying..." How do you simplify $(x+y+\dots)^{3/2}?$

Comment: The equation below 'after simplification' if strange!

Answer (score 6):

Sorry didn't really read your solution, but this might work:

Clearly $|a|,|b|,|c|,|d|\leq 3$ and thus $a^3\leq 3a^2$ and so on... and we are done.

Comment: And equality only if a^3 = 3a^2 etc, so a = 0 or a = 3 etc.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A=a^2, B=b^2, C=c^2, D=d^2$. You want to find the maximum of $\sum_{cyc}A^{3/2}$ on the set $\{A+B+C+D=9, A,B,C,D\geq 0\}$, i.e. the maximum of a convex function on a convex, closed and bounded set, namely a tetrahedron. By the properties of convex functions such maximum is attained at the vertices of the tetrahedron and it equals $9^{3/2}=27$.